# How to evaluate mutiple testing using one ROC-Curve

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, roc, evaluate

I ran out of memory (11G VRAM) while testing my CNN with 10 test images. I'm using the U-Net architecture, 20 training images each (1600x1200x1), 48x48 patches (190000 sub images) and batch size of 32 (recommended).
So right now I'm testing my network 5 times eatch 2 images. After that I want to evaluate my network using one ROC curve.

So here are my questions: Can I evaluate my network, if I split the testing? If yes, how can I manage it?
If not, what do I have to change in my config so that the memory doesn't run out?

btw I'm a beginner in NN and I'm sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I used [this github repository](https://github.com/orobix/retina-unet) as a base but my input images have a resolution of 1600x1200, not 584x565. The testing is quite the same.
I don't get the out of memory error when i run the testing with the original images from the DRIVE database.